# python recv() and eval()

Tags: python, recv

can someone please help me understand this code

```
clientsock.send("Welcome to Maths_Server 1.0\n")

try:
    clientsock.send("Enter the first number, so I can EVALuate it:\n")
    firstNum = eval(clientsock.recv(1024))
    firstNum = firstNum + firstNum + ord(flag[4]) + ord(flag[8]) + ord(flag[5])
    clientsock.send("Enter the second number, so I can EVALuate it:\n")
    secondNum = eval(clientsock.recv(1024))
    if secondNum == firstNum:
        clientsock.send("The flag is: " + flag + "\n")
        firstNum = 0
        secondNum = 0
except:
    pass

clientsock.close()
```

i want to know what does recv() does and how can i make the if statement true

Comment: this code is full of errors and security flaws. DON'T USE IT.

Comment: i am not using it, actually my mission is to know how to crack it (homework) but i don't understand what does recv do

Comment: `clientsock` is obviously a socket object. So https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv. Note, Googling `python recv` leads you to this exact page.

Comment: ok how can i know make the if statement true without knowing the value of firstnum

Comment: You don't have to crack anything, simple do `server.sendall('clientsock.sendall("Flag: %s" % flag)')` and read the result.

Comment: i can't change the code, it's a webserver and i am accessing it from netcat

Comment: they have provided me with a piece of the source code of the webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't determine the `firstNum` value because it's inputted by the user, so you input a random number into the `firstNum`, then for the `secondNum` you enter `firstNum`, so what this does is the eval() takes the `firstNum` value and convert it into string for the `secondNum` which will make the if-statement true. Hope this works out.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this riddle is this is actually the server code, but you need to make a client which will connect to that server, and produce equal results to get the flag.